# How to make a RadioButon without text?

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-button, android-widget

I just want a simple RadioBttun without text and I did the code below but what I get is a radiobutton widget with little space that is I think reserved to the text. So How should get rid of this space ?

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/rb_topup_item_account_selection_status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@null" />
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried removing this line 
`android:text="@null"` altogether ?

Comment: @Umair yes I did and I got the same result. Also I tried android:text="" but the same

Comment: Please post the layout in which you are using this button.

Comment: @Umair sorry but no need  and when I try to put the code the stackEditor insist and tell me that there is code more than what is explaned. It just a LinearLayout with three widgets: an icon, textview and a radiobutton

Comment: If I add a _RadioButton_ to any layout and I don't include the _android:text_ attribute, I get your desired result.

Comment: @NikosHidalgo It is strange I tried it but I got the same result

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the app theme or styling in general. Do you get the same in different devices/emulators?

Comment: @NikosHidalgo  there is no such a thing and yes I get the same result

Comment: I also get the "Desired" output when I didn't add the `text` attribute: [Result](https://i.imgur.com/WTSRVXz.png)

Comment: Shared your full layout XML code, it is working fine  without text null

Comment: Have you figure it out? I have the same issue when I add padding to radio button

Answer (score 23):

Just add the below attributes to the RadioButton element in your XML layout. It will remove the default padding.

```
android:minWidth="0dp"
android:minHeight="0dp"
```